# Breakpoints on Chrome DevTools for node won't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a node app with Chrom DevTools. Here is the instruction that I followed: 
[Instruction](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)

In brief I do this:
1- Run my app with command line `npm start`
2- Run the inspector with command `node --inspect-brk app.js`
3- Open chrome://inspect I see the following view:

[image]

4- click on "Open dedicated DevTools for node" link
5- I see thatit shows the files under (no domain) folder not (file:///) like bellow

[image]

When I ping the service with postman, breakpoints will not pause the app. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not experienced with nodejs, but have you tried to specify `debugger;` instruction in places where you want the application to stop. It should work.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Thanks for your comment, in the new method, there is no need to put debugger, you just simply add your breakpoints graphically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to inspect the target (deployed) folder and also I don't need step 1. When I run the debugger it will run the app. So instead of

```
node --inspect-brk app.js
```

I had to run this:

```
node --inspect-brk ./bin/www
```

Comment: are you sure that's what fixed it?  I am having the same problem and unfortunately this hasn't fixed it for me, so is it possible you did something else too that might have made a difference?

Comment: @randomsock Yes it works for me every time I run the command  "node --inspect-brk ./bin/www" and going to chrome://inspect on browser.